# How does Rindou's skill work?

Tags: battle-game-in-five-seconds

In *Deatte 5-byou de Battle* (*Battle Game in 5 Seconds*), Rindou's skill seems identical to Kirisaki's skill (namely, turning a piece of wood into a blade that can cut through anything).

But how come he can cut objects at a distance?

I hope that there's a logical explain to this. Because that seems to be what the anime tried to show, but I couldn't understand it.

Answer (score 1):

The explanation(s) given in the manga is that the inside of Rindou's sheath contains a layer of wood and by touching it while he draws his sword Rindou is able to use his ability to turn the inside of the scabbard into a "blade that can cut anything" which offers a very smooth surface to draw the blade against which I then assume gives him such draw speed the air pushed by the blade can cut things at a distance.

Ch 48 pg 7 for Kirisaki's thoughts:

[image: Kirisaki's theory]

Also take note of Ch 47's end card:

[image: Rindou's ability]

According to the blurb Rindou can cut apart space itself in a straight line using his Iaijutsu. Is either explanation plausible? Not really but it isn't any less plausible than firing an arm mounted cannon and not blowing your arm off with the recoil.